# c++ Function which returns data to a refrenced vector

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, function-pointers, stdvector

I have a function that reads a text file and populates a vector which is referenced as an argument.

```
vect.push_back(TempArray);
```

is the line that causes my error. Any thoughts?

```
Error   1   error C2664: 'void std::vector<_Ty>::push_back(double *&&)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::vector<_Ty>' to 'double *&&'    d:\aul_c++_12102014\aul_c++_rk_version_12182014\aul\aul\projection.h    206 1   AUL

int projection::import_inputTables(string input_file, string output_file, int dimen,    vector<double*> &vect, long col_filler, long row_filler, string delim, int OptArgVar)                   
{                   

long i=0,j=0,k=0;               

int total_Col = dimen;
long MaxLinesNum = 100000;  
const string DELIM = delim;
string Line;
string LineCell;
long LineCounter = 0;
long LinesRead = 0;
int LineReadPoint = 0;

//Determines number of lines to be read
    if (OptArgVar == 0) //Read untill the end
    { 
        MaxLinesNum = 100000;
    }
    else if (OptArgVar == 1)
    {
        MaxLinesNum = 1;
    }
    else if (OptArgVar == 2)
    {
        MaxLinesNum = 51;
    }

ifstream input_stream;  
input_stream.open(input_file);

if (input_stream.is_open())
{
    while( MaxLinesNum > LinesRead )
    {
        getline(input_stream,Line);
        if (LineCounter >= col_filler)
        {
            vector<double> TempArray;

            for (j = 0; (j <  total_Col); j++) //Column Loop
            {
                LineCell = Line.substr(0,Line.find(DELIM));
                Line.erase(0,Line.find(DELIM) + DELIM.length());

                TempArray.push_back(stod(LineCell));

            }

            vect.push_back(TempArray);
            vector<double> ().swap(TempArray);          

            LinesRead++;
            LineCounter++;
        }
        else
        {
            LineCounter++;
        }

        if (MaxLinesNum == LinesRead) //Read only the needed number of lines --- Will read entire file if OptArgVar is set to 0
            break;
    }
}
else
{
    cout << "Could Not Open File" << endl;
}

//PRINT STATEMENT DO NOT DELETE
input_stream.close();

return vect.size(); 

/*ofstream out(output_file);    
out.precision(10);
for (j = 0; j < vect.size(); j++){              
    for (i = 0; i <= total_Col; i++){           
        out << vect.at(j)[i]<< '\t';        
    }           
    out << '\n';    
}               
out.close();*/



}
```

Comment: You are trying to `push_back` a `vector<double>` to a `vector<double*>`? I'm not sure what you're trying to do there.

Comment: @RomanKhutoretsky: I believe you're looking for a `vector<vector<double>>` instead of a `vector<double *>`.

Comment: so I created a vector 2D vector in my program. I use this function to populate that vector via reading a text file. I created a vector TempArray. I read each comma(or other symbol) delimited line and and assign each element to my TempArray. So it should have in it 1 row of my final vector. I wanted to push this vector to my Final output vector (vect) as it finishes reading each line so that at the end the final vector is a 2d array with all of the data I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like

```
vector<double*> &vect
```

should be

```
vector<vector<double>> &vect
```